# Creating a Mapping Model by code instead of XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have read the Core Data documentation about migration. However, I see only how to [create a mapping model in XCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH5-SW1). How can I do the same only by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mapping model is for heavy migration.  Heavy migration does not work well on iOS (or at all).

Instead, you should be doing a lightweight migration.  That will be faster and will work on iOS correctly.

As for creating a mapping model in code, you cannot.  It can only be created by Xcode and therefore if you **MUST** do something other than a lightweight migration you are better writing the migration code yourself.  For example, exporting your old data into arrays and dictionaries and then importing it into the new structure.  That is effectively what a heavy migration is doing.